# Get computed font size for DOM element in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ckeditor, font-size

Is it possible to detect the computed `font-size` of a DOM element, taking into consideration generic settings made elsewhere (In the `body` tag for example), inherited values, and so on?

A framework-independent approach would be nice, as I'm working on a script that should work standalone, but that is not a requirement of course.

Background: I'm trying to tweak [CKEditor's](http://ckeditor.com/) font selector plugin (source [here](http://svn.fckeditor.net/CKEditor/releases/stable/_source/plugins/font/plugin.js)) so that it always shows the font size of the current cursor position (as opposed to only when within a `span` that has an explicit `font-size` set, which is the current behaviour).

Comment: "Computed" as in the size in pixels?

Comment: For the current scenario: pixels only, but in general it would be very nice to be able to get both the defined value (px,pt,em) and the pixel one.

Comment: @Pekka: if it's pixels only you're good. `pt`, `em` etc are going to be impossible, only IE's `currentStyle` can get it right.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You could try to use the non-standard IE [`element.currentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535231(VS.85).aspx) property, otherwise you can look for the [DOM Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSview-getComputedStyle) standard [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) method if available :

```
function getStyle(el,styleProp) {
  var camelize = function (str) {
    return str.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function(str, letter){
      return letter.toUpperCase();
    });
  };

  if (el.currentStyle) {
    return el.currentStyle[camelize(styleProp)];
  } else if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
    return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null)
                               .getPropertyValue(styleProp);
  } else {
    return el.style[camelize(styleProp)]; 
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
var element = document.getElementById('elementId');
getStyle(element, 'font-size');
```

More info:

- [Get Styles](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html) (QuirksMode)

**Edit:** Thanks to *@Crescent Fresh*, *@kangax* and *@Pekka* for the comments.

Changes:

- Added `camelize` function, since properties containing hypens, like `font-size`, must be accessed as camelCase (eg.: `fontSize`) on the `currentStyle` IE object.
- Checking the existence of `document.defaultView` before accessing `getComputedStyle`.
- Added last case, when `el.currentStyle` and `getComputedStyle` are not available, get the inline CSS property via `element.style`.

Comment: This looks great, will try it out.

Comment: Be careful, `currentStyle` and `getComputedStyle` are fundamentally different: http://erik.eae.net/archives/2007/07/27/18.54.15/ `getComputedStyle` is incapable of getting the *inherited* style, and always *computes* it as `px`, whether the value was declared as `px` or not.

Comment: Thanks for the caveat. Very good to know. For the job at hand it's fine, as stated above.

Comment: It's actually `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle`, not `window.getComputedStyle` (MDC gets it wrong, or considers its own — Mozilla — implementation only). `getComputedStyle` is specified to be a member of `AbstractView`, which `document.defaultView` implements, and there's really no guarantee that `window == document.defaultView` (neither in specs, nor in practice; in fact, Safari 2.x is a good example of `window != document.defaultView`). It's interesting that PPK does similar mistake in getstyles article that you linked to (testing `defaultView` on `window`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help folks. I got it working with Firefox but am stuck with IE. If you'd like to take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956573/runtimestyle-in-ie7-8

Comment: Sorted. @CMS, if I'm not mistaken you need to edit your answer to point out that `currentStyle` will accept camelized properties only (e.g. fontSize) while `getPropertyValue` works with the original form (font-size).

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback guys, edited to check `document.defaultView` instead of `window` as @kangax points out, also added a `camelize` function to get the right properties when working with `el.currentStyle`, any further feedback is really appreciated!

Comment: Well, it would also be a good idea to check existence of `document.defaultView` before accessing `getComputedStyle` on it.

Comment: Does someone know why this doesn't work with jQuery ? if I replace var element = document.getElementById('elementId');
getStyle(element, 'font-size');
by getStyle($('#elementId'), 'font-size') there is a javascript error...

Comment: @Vinze: that's because `$('#elementId')` returns a jQuery object while CMS's `getStyle` function expects a DOM element. Use `getStyle($('#elementId')[0], 'font-size')` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like jQuery (1.9 at least) uses `getComputedStyle()` or `currentStyle` itself when you use `$('#element')[.css][1]('fontSize')`, so you really shouldn't have to bother with more complicated solutions if you're OK using jQuery.

Tested in IE 7-10, FF and Chrome

Comment: or more simply : `$('mySelector').css('font-size')`

Answer (score 2):

To overcome the 'em' problem I have quickly written a function, if the font-size in ie is 'em' the function calculates with the body font-size.

```
        function getFontSize(element){
        var size = computedStyle(element, 'font-size');
        if(size.indexOf('em') > -1){
            var defFont = computedStyle(document.body, 'font-size');
            if(defFont.indexOf('pt') > -1){
                defFont = Math.round(parseInt(defFont)*96/72);
            }else{
                defFont = parseInt(defFont);
            }
            size = Math.round(defFont * parseFloat(size));
        } 
        else if(size.indexOf('pt') > -1){
            size = Math.round(parseInt(size)*96/72)
        }
        return parseInt(size);
    }

    function computedStyle(element, property){
        var s = false;
        if(element.currentStyle){
            var p = property.split('-');
            var str = new String('');
            for(i in p){
                str += (i > 0)?(p[i].substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + p[i].substr(1)):p[i];
            }
            s = element.currentStyle[str];
        }else if(window.getComputedStyle){
            s = window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue(property);
        }
        return s;
    }
```