# Get computed font-family in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, computed-style

This is a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955048/get-computed-font-size-for-dom-element-in-js).

I am working on a component for the [CKEditor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CKEditor), a tweaked version of the font drop-down menus that always display the currently selected font family / size values, no matter where they were defined, using `computedStyle` and consorts.

As you can see in the other question, determining the font size works cross-browser now. Now I am having trouble working with the `fontFamily` attribute. My generic "computed style" function returns only the full font string that was defined, e.g.

```
Times New Roman, Georgia, Serif
```

What I need, in order to match the setting against the entries in the font family dropdown, is a **fixed font name** of the **actual font** of the DOM element I am checking.

Can this be done somehow, at least for the most common web fonts?

Answer (score 7):

Here goes a way to get the computed font-family with JavaScript from the DOM:

```
let para = document.querySelector('p');
let compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(para);
let computedFontFamily = compStyles.getPropertyValue('font-family') // e.g. "Times New Roman"
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: This will return something like this:  `Segoe UI, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif`.  Is there anyway to limit the return to just `Segou UI` (the first font)?

Comment: 2023 checkup: is there a way to get the name of the font actually being **loaded and rendered**?

Comment: @rudtek if you need just the first in the list, you can simply split the string on commas. if you need the actual font loaded (`segoe ui` does not exist on non-windows devices), i think it's still not possible....

Answer (score 3):

The UA picks the first font in the list that it finds installed. The fonts installed on the OS are not really a part of the DOM, so the best you can do is guess.

Comment: You're right. Paul D. Waite presents a workaround that I'm not going to use in this case, but makes it possible to sort it out.