# How can you determine what font from the CSS stack is being used?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I use Firebug avidly and in the CSS-"computed" tab it will only show me the declared stack, but not which font has actually been used by the browser. Aside from removing fonts one-by-one and looking for a change (or having amazing font recognition skills) is there a way to determine what font has actually been rendered by the browser?

Comment: Seems to be possible but is hard. Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960817/get-computed-font-family-in-javascript

Comment: <rant>You shouldn't really worry about it, because the exact same font will render differently in different browsers/systems. It's not reliable no matter how you look at it.</rant>

You might try Chrome's developer tools, it seems to show full font names. The chosen font in that list is going to be the first one which actually exists on your system.

Comment: Nicholas FWIW what I actually want to do is find out which of several esoteric fonts in their stack is being used on a given website.

Comment: Agreed, duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960817/get-computed-font-family-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also read theese:

> http://unitinteractive.com/blog/2008/06/26/better-css-font-stacks/
>
> [Detecting which font was used in a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845/detecting-font-in-javascript)
>
> https://superuser.com/questions/43280/utility-to-determine-the-font-used-on-a-site
>
> http://remysharp.com/2008/07/08/how-to-detect-if-a-font-is-installed-only-using-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

This firefox add-on will help: https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/4415