# CSS: how to have different sizes for each font

Tags: css, font-size, font-face

I have a website the uses "arial narrow". To avoid compatibility problems I made a @font-face version of that font using "Font Squirrel" font-face generator (http://www.fontsquirrel.com), but when I'm on a system that doesn't have the native "Arial Narrow" and then it loads online via @font-face, the font is greater than the native "Arial Narrow"; I'm using absolute size in px for the fonts.

Is there a way to set different sizes for the native and online font?

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'ArialNarrow';
src: url('/fonts/arialn-webfont.eot');
src: local('☺'), url('/fonts/arialn-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/fonts/arialn-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/fonts/arialn-webfont.svg#webfontNZumFher') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal; }
```

and below:

```
font-family: 'Arial Narrow', 'ArialNarrow', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
```

Thanks in advance, sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

In theory, the CSS 2.0 and CSS 3 property `font-size-adjust` was created for that use, but its support is weak. No IE (surprise!), Fx 3.0+ and afaik no support in Saf 4 and no Op 10.5.

I wonder why both Arial Narrow aren't the same size (and have no answer) but I'd like to point out that Arial Narrow is licensed by [Ascender to Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=22) and can be purchased here: http://www.fontslive.com/font/arial-narrow-regular.aspx (and this condensed family was created by Monotype).
For a non-commercial website http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_fonts_for_the_Web says that it's too late (2002) and that the packages should be kept in their original format and filenames: embedding modifies the former.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, similar questions have been asked and the conclusion was always "can't be done" (at least not reliably across browsers, kudos to @Felipe for bringing up those CSS properties - didn't know them).

It's difficult even using JavaScript, because it's damn difficult to find out which font has been actually used by the browser in the end.

See also: [Get computed font-family in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960817/get-computed-font-family-in-javascript)