# Change the size of a single (primary) font, without changing the fallback size

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

The font that I have to use (Futura PT from TypeKit) is smaller in size than the fallback fonts (helvetica,arial,sans-serif).

font-size:120%; seems to make the font look correct, but the fallback fonts then appear larger as well.

I just need futura-pt to display at 120% but not effect any other font sizes.

Is this possible? Either through css or js?

Comment: good question... the answer might be "no" for css only.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970947/specify-fallback-font-sizes-in-css

Comment: @ggzone I don't think it is possible with a css only solution, but I was hoping they'd be some JavaScript that could change the size of a font prior to css.

Comment: yes i mean with JS you can check the font-family style and if its not futura pt then you can change the font-size to your needed 120%