# Different font weight for different fonts

Tags: css, fonts

I use `Bold`, `Medium` and `Normal` font weights on my website, that's `700`, `500` and `400` respectively.

I use `Helvetica Neue` font and as a fallback for systems that doesn't have it installed I want to use `Open Sans`. The problem is `Open Sans` doesn't have `Medium` style.

I want my elements that I used to define as `font-weight: 500` have `font-weight: 600` if the browser uses `Open Sans`. Is it possible somehow?

There's a similar question at Stack Overflow: [How to set different font-weight for fallback font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22152420/how-to-set-different-font-weight-for-fallback-font) but I'cant get the result I need using techniqe described in an accepted answer.

I need something like

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'semibold';
  src: 'Helvetica Neue':500, 'Open Sans':600;      
}
```

Not sure how to do it though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really define weight in a font-face declaration. Instead, `font-weight` is used there [as a gatekeeper to match the font](https://css-tricks.com/whats-deal-declaring-font-properties-font-face/#article-header-id-1) and not to pass styles to the element.

It seems like overkill, but you could use this [JavaScript function by Sam Clarke](https://www.samclarke.com/javascript-is-font-available/) as a starting point to see if the font is available, and then conditionally modify the font-weight following the logic that works best for your specific requirements.

For a simplified example with just these two fonts, you might set up the CSS like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: h-semibold;
  src: local('Helvetica Neue');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: os-semibold;
  src: local('Open Sans');
}

.semibold {
  font-family: h-semibold, os-semibold;
}

.w5 {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.w6 {
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

Then, using the function linked above, you put something like this in your JS to conditionally load the weight classes depending on font support:

```
var semibold = document.querySelectorAll('.semibold');

if (isFontAvailable('h-semibold')) {
    semibold.forEach(result => {
      result.className += ' ' + 'w5';
    });
} else {
    semibold.forEach(result => {
      result.className += ' ' + 'w6';
    });
}
```

You'll doubtless work out a more elegant solution if you really need to carry it through.

Comment: But it there any way to do it without JS code? I think it won't work quite well in the SPA where parts of the page could be added dynamically and still have improper css classes.