# Simple getComputedStyle in Prototype JS?

Tags: javascript, css, prototypejs, computed-style

Is there an easy cross-browser way to get computed style of an element in PrototypeJS, without checking document.defaultView... and other properties? ...so that the code looked like

```
var elt = $$('.xyz')[k],
    border = elt.getComputedStyle('border-bottom-width')
```

PrototypeJs provides `getDimensions`, `-Width`, and `-Height` methods that return **computed** dimensions, but there's no way to get other computed styles, like borders, backgrounds, etc.

I've found several stand-alone [implementations](http://robertnyman.com/2006/04/24/get-the-rendered-style-of-an-element/) of getComputedStyle, but maybe there's a patch/plugin for PrototypeJS that does that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prototype's [`getStyle`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/getStyle) method encapsulates most of the cross-browser computed style work you're looking for:

```
var bgColor = $(element).getStyle('background-color');
```

From the docs:

> This method looks up the CSS property
>   of an element whether it was applied
>   inline or in a stylesheet. It works
>   around browser inconsistencies
>   regarding float, opacity, which
>   returns a value between 0 (fully
>   transparent) and 1 (fully opaque),
>   position properties (left, top, right
>   and bottom) and when getting the
>   dimensions (width or height) of hidden
>   elements.

However, this method will not return styles applied in a stylesheet in Internet Explorer <= 8, because it uses the getComputedStyle() method, which is the incorrect method for versions 8 and lower: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html

Comment: But it returns only the inline style.

Comment: @culebron: No it doesn't, it returns the computed style, incorporating those defined in stylesheets. Check the source yourself: http://prototypejs.org/assets/2009/8/31/prototype.js  (search for getStyle). You'll find `getComputedStyle` right in there.

Comment: But this isn't fully cross browser, IE <= 8 needs .currentStyle, not .getComputedStyle(). Check yourself: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of.

This is probably because the "get computed style" implementations are so different that it's hardly possible to guarantee uniform results (Which renders them useless for a cross-browser framework).

For example, getting the computed font size cross-browser is not always possible, as I learned in **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955048/get-computed-font-size-for-dom-element-in-js)**.

Comment: Yep, I've seen it. This question shows in the top 1st page when googling for "prototype js get computed style"

Comment: Most (all?) js libraries have a function for getting the computed/current style for a particular property. See my answer for the prototype way.