# In GWT how to know all the styles applied to a given element (by id or class name)

Tags: javascript, css, gwt, jsni

I have the following problem : in my GWT project there is a "main" css file for the application, inline css in the DOM that come from the application computation and a css file that is bundled in an archive uploaded to the application and dynamically loaded.

Now I need for an `Element` to find which CSS rules are applied, coming from either of the three sources. As I understand, GWT's `getStyle()` function only returns informations that are in the DOM.

What's the simplest way to achieve this ?

Edit : If possible, I search for a client-side solution (in java or javascript) rather than a server-side one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to my problem (in fact two but I'm going for the first) :

1. Using [jQuery's css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) that does what I wanted
2. A pure javascript solution in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955048/get-computed-font-size-for-dom-element-in-js)

I now just have to write a JNSI wrapper for the jQuery function...

Edit : Found a third solution which correspond exactly to what I want : [GQuery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) which is a port of jQuery to GWT and contains (according to the main page) 98% of jQuery's core functionalities.