# Using javascript, how to get the position of an element

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, positioning

like the title says, how to get the element's x, y positions with respect to their location in the web page and their positioning schemes like absolute, relative etc.

Answer (score 8):

In a modern browser, getBoundingClientRect and getClientRects will give you rect objects describing your element.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getClientRects

If you have to work with IE8, then you'll have to do different things in different browsers to get correct answers (e.g. object-detect getBoundingClientRect and fall back on some other method if it's not present).

The jQuery `offset()` calculation and the Quirksmode `findPos` will give incorrect answers in any browser that does subpixel positioning (e.g. Firefox or IE9), because they will round the answer to an integer number of pixels.  Depending on what you're doing, that may or may not be ok.

Answer (score 5):

With jQuery:

```
var $elt = $('select an element however'),
    cssPosition = $elt.css('position'),
    offset = $elt.offset(),
    top = offset.top,
    left = offset.left;
```

Without jQuery, use [Quirksmode's `findPos` function](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html):

```
var elt = document.getElementBy...,
    pos = findPos(elt),
    top = pos[1],
    left = pos[0];
```

Getting the computed CSS `position` value without a library is [another can of worms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955048/get-computed-font-size-for-dom-element-in-js). It boils down to:

- [`element.currentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535231%28VS.85%29.aspx) (IE)
- [`getComputedStyle(element)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) (real browsers)

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but... how is my answer _not_ JavaScript? jQuery is JavaScript, and I also showed how to do it without jQuery.

Comment: jQuery's positioning isn't always correct, and PPK's version is simplilstic - it will fail in some cases. Browsers have various positioning quirks, IE's strict, compat and quirks modes add to the mix. Keep things simple and life is much easier.

Comment: @RobG so what do you suggest instead? I've never really had issues with jQuery's algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Check out this

**JS:**

```
function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        curleft = obj.offsetLeft
        curtop = obj.offsetTop
        while (obj = obj.offsetParent) {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft
            curtop += obj.offsetTop
        }
    }
    return [curleft,curtop];
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="ser">&nbsp;TEST</div>
```

**RETURN CALL:**

```
alert(findPos(document.getElementById('ser')));
```

I hope its help to you

Comment: FYI: that snippet contains an error. The variable "curtop" is contaminating global scope. I wrote to the guy at quirksmode.org about it just now. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html