# get computed font size of GWT Label

Tags: css, gwt, label, font-size

I'd like to be able to access the font size of a GWT Label. I've tried:

```
String fontSize = label.getElement().getStyle().getFontSize()
```

but this seems to only be for font sizes that have been programatically set (and not font sizes that are decided by CSS rules). Any ideas?

Thanks,

~Owen

Answer (score 2):

If it is the [computed size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) you are looking for, GWT does not provide it out of the box, but you should be able to use a simple `JSNI` to retrieve it. Something like:

```
public static native String getComputedStyleProperty(Element element, String property)  /*-{
  if ($doc.defaultView && $doc.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
    return $doc.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue(property);
  }
  return "";
}-*/;
```

Untested but should get you started. Do note that, the `property` should be `camelCase` and, for IE < 9, you should also check for `currentStyle`. Also a fallback based on `element`'s style property should be returned, instead the empty string.
See also [Get computed font size for DOM element in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955048/get-computed-font-size-for-dom-element-in-js).

Answer (score 0):

No,   [getFontSize](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Style.html#getFontSize%28%29)()  returns `CSS property only`.

Give a try like below:

```
   String fontsize= DOM.getStyleAttribute(label.getElement(), "font-size");
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, it returns "" when the label has a font size of "24px" (as inherited from <body>).

Comment: Strange.Are you able to see that in firebug ?see i updated the property to "font-size".Please check once

Comment: 1. I can see it when I "Inspect element" in Chrome.
2. Camelcase is required - "font-size" throws an error.

Comment: Really strange.How much your are getting and how much its in the firebug?