# JavaScript onclick() text size increase with EventListener

Tags: javascript, html, button, action, handler

I am trying to implement the following to increase text size based on button click. I am trying to use one handler for this. The idea is to increase/decrease the fontsize for the text in "demo" area by +/-5 px. But I am not getting the desired result.

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Change font size</p>
        <div id="main_area1">
            <button id="button1" value="larger" type="button" onclick="changeFontSize(this)">Larger</button>
        </div>
        <div id="main_area2">
            <button id="button2" vale="smaller" type="button" onclick="changeFontSize(this)">Smaller</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="demo">HOW_BIG_OR_SMALL_AM_I</p>
        </div>
        <script>
            function changeFontSize(target) {
                if (target == document.getElementById("button1")) {
                    document.getElementById("demo").style.fontSize = document.getElementById("demo").style.fontSize + "5px";
                } else if (target == document.getElementById("button2")) {
                    document.getElementById("demo").style.fontSize = document.getElementById("demo").style.fontSize + "-5px";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I checked it in developers console, I see that my target has the same `value` as button1. But I cannot see the font size increasing (same is true for button2).

I tried to use my java knowledge as much as I can, but not getting anywhere. I think I might be using the wrong element Id or I am not registering the handler correctly.

Any help or kind suggestion is appreciated ! Thanks.

Comment: Your `demo` DIV doesn't have a `font-size` style. So `.style.fontSize` is returning an empty string, and then you're appending `5px` to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of points:

1. The `style` object won't have values that are applied via stylesheets; to get those, on a standards-compliant browser you use `getComputedStyle`. (On older IE, you use the `currentStyle` property.)
2. You need to parse the value you get, because it's a string.
3. Any time you find yourself repeatedly writing the same thing over and over, consider whether to do it once and remember it in a variable.

This does the trick on standards-compliant browsers and should work on older IE as well:

```js
function changeFontSize(target) {
  var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
  var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle
        ? getComputedStyle(demo) // Standards
        : demo.currentStyle;     // Old IE
  var fontSize;

  if (computedStyle) { // This will be true on nearly all browsers
      fontSize = parseFloat(computedStyle && computedStyle.fontSize);

      if (target == document.getElementById("button1")) {
        fontSize += 5;
      } else if (target == document.getElementById("button2")) {
        fontSize -= 5;
      }
      demo.style.fontSize = fontSize + "px";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Change font size</p>
<div id="main_area1">
  <button id="button1" value="larger" type="button" onclick="changeFontSize(this)">Larger</button>
</div>
<div id="main_area2">
  <button id="button2" vale="smaller" type="button" onclick="changeFontSize(this)">Smaller</button>
</div>
<div>
  <p id="demo">HOW_BIG_OR_SMALL_AM_I</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955048/get-computed-font-size-for-dom-element-in-js

Comment: You can replace that under-performant `if` with this code: `switch(target.id){ case "button1": fontSize+=5; break; case "button2": fontSize-=5; break; }` (structure it well, please). Since `id`s are supposed to be unique,there is no need to fetch the elements each time I click the button. This is an improvement in readability and performance.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: Yes, I decided not to touch that bit.

Comment: And keep application logic out of the markup. Avoid `onclick=""` and use `addEventListener` or some equivalent like jQuery.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I was just providing a suggestion. You can add it as a sidenote for an improvement.

Comment: @Sukima         in the case of Event Listener or JQuery will `addEventListener("click", changeFontSize(this))` work? Because I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: It won't work because `changeFontSize(this)` does not return a function. Either return a function that the click handler can use or perhaps you want `addEventListener("click", changeFontSize)`.

Comment: @hagubear: See Sukima's comment above. That would make it work with `addEventListener`. (Beware that `addEventListener` isn't available on IE8, or IE9+ in the misnamed "compatibility" mode.)

Comment: I used `button1.addEventListener("click",function(){changeFontSize(this);}, true}` as my even listener registration. But inside my `changeFontSize(event)` function I am using `switch(event.id)` to determine if it's button1 or button2. It's stopped working :(. Any idea if I am doing something wrong? Using Firefox 22.0.0.4917.

Comment: @hagubear: The event doesn't have an `id`. Use `button1.addEventListener("click", changeFontSize, true}` and `switch (this.id)`.