# How increase and decrease font size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having trouble with the following problem. I have two buttons: + and - when press one of them, let's say + button. The size of the p span h1 a elements shoudl increase. Please Help!!!

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: you can use Jquery

Comment: Change the `font-size` on `:root` and use `em` units for everything.

Comment: @kannanD.S - Why jQuery? You can do this very easily in vanilla js and the question does not say jQuery.

Comment: I tried java script. Using DOM, I just changed the fontsize of the body

Comment: If you actually showed us the code you are using maybe we can tell you why that happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mocked your requirement and tried to solve your problem. Solution **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/ashish_88/xpvt214o/572069/)**

```
var fontsize = parseInt($('#mytext').css("font-size"));
  $('#mytext').css('font-size', fontsize+5);
```

you may change how much you want to increase fontsize, I am just increasing by 5 for example.

Please let me know, if you are looking for same or anything else?

Comment: You should also let the OP know that your solution requires jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

U can use Javascript to resolve this.

For example:

```js
function IncreaseHeader(){
 //Get the tag you want to change
 var headerTag = document.getElementById('header_tag');
 
 // Get the current font size
 var currentFontSize = headerTag.style.fontSize;
 
 //Take out the px in the end
 currentFontSize = currentFontSize.slice(0, -2);
 
 //Make currenFontSize an Integer
 currentFontSize = parseInt(currentFontSize);
 
 //Make new font size while increase currenFontSize by 1
 var newFontSize = currentFontSize + 1;
 
 //Make newFontsize a string and add px in the end
 newFontSize = newFontSize.toString() + "px";
 
 //Set new style
 headerTag.style.fontSize = newFontSize;
}

function DecreaseHeader(){
 //Get the tag you want to change
 var headerTag = document.getElementById('header_tag');
 
 // Get the current font size
 var currentFontSize = headerTag.style.fontSize;
 
 //Take out the px in the end
 currentFontSize = currentFontSize.slice(0, -2);
 
 //Make currenFontSize an Integer
 currentFontSize = parseInt(currentFontSize);
 
 //Make new font size while decrease currenFontSize by 1
 var newFontSize = currentFontSize - 1;
 
 //Make newFontsize a string and add px in the end
 newFontSize = newFontSize.toString() + "px";
 
 //Set new style
 headerTag.style.fontSize = newFontSize;
}
```

```html
    <h1 id="header_tag" style="font-size: 20px;">Hello</h1>
 <button onclick="IncreaseHeader()">+</button>
 <button onclick="DecreaseHeader()">-</button>
```

Take care. The height attribute of the h1 u want to increse must be inline in this cae.

Answer (score -5):

Can you be more specific about the question.
There are couple of ways . One of the ways is by using pure javascript. This might help you :
[JavaScript onclick() text size increase with EventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652595/javascript-onclick-text-size-increase-with-eventlistener)

Comment: This should be a comment at best. If you want to post an answer you should pull all the relevant information out of that link and use it to write a fully self-contained answer here

Comment: thanx for letting me know , I didn't know this.