# How to get inline CSS style property from element

Tags: jquery, css, properties, inline

I have problem with getting inline css style properties.

I'd tried doing that with:

```
 var inline_css = $(this).attr("style");
```

but...

it works only when element does not have any other css properties outside inline style... like:

```
.our_element {something: some;}
```

Any ideas how to get only inline CSS properties from element which has many other CSS properties?

Comment: How does the HTML look like? You may want to use `this.style`.

Comment: for example: <h1 style="font-size: 33px;">This is a test2</h1>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get computed font size for DOM element in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955048/get-computed-font-size-for-dom-element-in-js)

Comment: I don't understand if you want `only inline CSS property` or all???

Comment: @IonicăBizău: Pretty sure it's exactly *not* that question.

Answer (score 27):

If you mean a style from the `style` attribute, you can access them directly on the element instance:

```
var color = this.style.color;
```

That will give you the `color` *only* if it's in the `style` attribute (not applied via stylesheet).

The names you use are camelCase if you use literal notation, e.g. `this.style.fontSize`, or you can also use the CSS dashed style using brackets notation, `this.style["font-size"]`.

Just for completeness, if you want the information whether it comes from the `style` attribute *or* a stylesheet, jQuery's CSS function does just that:

```
var color = $(this).css("color");
```

---

From your comment:

> thanks, but if I want all properties can I use this.style ??

If you want **all** of the inline-styles as text, either get the `style` attribute (as you're doing) or use `this.style.cssText`.

If you want **all** of the styles, regardless of whether they're inline or not, as an object, use `getComputedStyle` (or `currentStyle` on obsolete browsers like IE8):

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle ? getComputedStyle(this) : this.currentStyle;
if (style) { // This will be true on major browsers
    var color = style.color; // Or whatever
}
```

**Examples**:

```js
var div = document.querySelector(".foo");
snippet.log("div.style.fontSize: " + div.style.fontSize);
snippet.log("div.style.color: " + div.style.color);
snippet.log("div.style.cssText: " + div.style.cssText);
snippet.log("$(div).attr('style'): " + $(div).attr('style'));
snippet.log("$(div).css('fontSize'): " + $(div).css('fontSize') + " (note that's in pixels, probably, not pt)");
snippet.log("$(div).css('color'): " + $(div).css('color'));
```

```css
.foo {
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo" style="font-size: 12pt">
  This has an inline <code>font-size: 12pt</code> and
  CSS (not inline) giving <code>font-size: 14pt</code> and <code>color: green</code>.
</div>
<hr>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, but if I want all properties can I use this.style  ??

Comment: @luke9999: I don't understand the question. In your question, you said you wanted to get *one* of them.

Comment: sorry then, I mean all inline properties... ;/

Comment: @luke9999 So what's wrong with `$(this).attr("style");`??? Do you mean these properties could be overwritten by other rules or what? Can you provide concrete sample replicating your issue?

Comment: it works but its getting properties from file not inline style ;/

Comment: @luke9999: No, `.attr("style")` will not give you CSS-applied properties. Only the content of the `style` attribute.

Comment: @luke9999: Anyway, I've added examples to the answer to show what you get from the `style` attribute, the `style` property, and jQuery's CSS. Note how both the `style` attribute and property do *not* include CSS-applied styles.

Answer (score 0):

As old as this is, the actual question was on getting all computed styles on a given element.

What you were actually wanting to use it the [`Window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method.

With [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=getComputedStyle) going back, further than the original question.

### Example:

```js
var ourElement = document.querySelector(".ourElement");
var ourElementStyles = window.getComputedStyle(ourElement);

ourElement.textContent += ourElementStyles.color;
```

```css
.ourElement {
  color: rgb(0, 255, 0) !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="ourElement" style="color:rgb(255,0,0)">color: </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's an old post but this is the answer that can be helpful for others. You can try the below code -

**HTML code like -**

```
<p style="color: red; height: 300px">
```

**jQuery code -**

```
let height = $('p').get(0).style.height;
let color = $('p').get(0).style.color;
```

**Output below -**

```js
let height = $('p').get(0).style.height;
let color = $('p').get(0).style.color;

$('#output').html( 'Color: ' + color + '<br> Height: ' + height );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="color: red; height: 300px">
<div id="output"></div>
```