# How to get all dynamically set inline-style CSS in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to get all the styles which has been set dynamically (which applies as inline-styles) on an element.

For example

```
<span class="text" style="color: rgb(128, 128, 255); font-size: 24px;">Name</span>
```

I want to get the value of style attribute in a JS variable and save it.
I have tried using jQuery's [.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)('style'), but it's giving ***undefined***

Also, As suggested here [How to get inline CSS style property from element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904820/how-to-get-inline-css-style-property-from-element#answer-32904843) to use

```
getComputedStyle
```

but to get styles I need to mention all the styles like

```
var el = document.querySelector("selector")
console.log(el.style.SomeStyle);
```

but there are various styles which a user can set dynamically.
So, do I need to mention all the **inline-styles** individually or is there some better way to get that?

Thanks in advance for any help

**Update from the [void's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1496715/void) comment:**

As described here [Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element#answer-5830517)

[marknadal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/342275/marknadal) had wrote a function that retrieves both inline and external styles, but I just need the inline-styles irrespective of all css classes attached

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getAttribute`:

```
const el = document.querySelector('my-element');
const styleStr = el.getAttribute('style');
```

for example, the following:

```
<div style="color:blue;display:flex;"></div>
```

would yield:

```
'color:blue;display:flex;'
```

You could then use a regex or something to parse it as needed. I'd recommend converting into an array of arrays or a similar structure rather than an object since you'll likely be unsure of what values are available (this is a simple way of doing that, and there is likely a much more efficient way to break it down. I'll leave that to you):

```
// gives [ ['color', 'blue'], ['display', 'flex'] ]
str.slice(0, str.length - 1).split(';').map(x => x.split(':'))
```

You could convert to an object and use a `for in` loop along with `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` as well.

jQuery alternative:

```
const els = $('my-element');
els.each((i, el) => {
  const styleStr = els.attr('style');
  const styles = styleStr.slice(0, styleStr.length - 1).split(';').map(x => x.split(':'));
});
```

Comment: [treyhakanson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5495358/treyhakanson), please see the comment i have posted in FRS's answer. Thanks

Comment: you can use `querySelectorAll` and iterate over that and it will work. In jQuery the solution is identical, just use `.attr` instead of `getAttribute`. I know you said you tried this and it didn't work, but you must have an error elsewhere because I have used `.attr('style')` before and it works fine

Comment: indeed i was doing some mistake, It worked just now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over object available under element's 'style' field as follows:

> **Warning** That object contains also **all** possible styling of element (with non-numeric property keys), so looping with e.g. for (sth in styles) **won't** work. You need to iterate styles in array-like way like shown below.

```
var el = document.querySelector("selector");
var styles = el.style;

for (var i = 0, len = styles.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var name = styles[i];
    var value = styles[value];

    console.log(name); // shows style name, e.g.: color, padding, etc
    console.log(value); // shows style value, e.g.: #fff, 20px, etc
}
```

Comment: [FRS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8805801/frs) Is it possible in jQuery? as this solution is not working for me as I have various continuous elements which i need to get by iterating.