# Jquery vs Javascript: getting css style object shows different result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have the following code:

In my html

```
<h1 id="heading">My Site</h1>
```

In my css

```
#heading{
   font-size: 16px;
   color: #333333;
}
```

When in console I do

```
document.getElementById("heading").style.fontSize
```

it gives: **""**

but when I do

```
$("#heading").css("fontSize")
```

it gives: **16px**

Even if I print the whole style object, vanilla javascript shows all blank values but jquery shows correct results.

Why is there a difference between the two?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/a/15195345/2887133 ---- http://stackoverflow.com/a/1955160/2887133

Comment: jquery is javascript, jquery is javascript, jquery is javascript....... if you ever wonder how jquery does something it's very easy to look it up! because all jquery is is a library around regular javascript functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because jQuery's css function gives you the computed style, whereas Element.style.fontSize gives you only styles that have been applied inline. The vanilla equivalent to the jQuery code would be this:

```
var heading = document.getElementById("heading");
window.getComputedStyle(heading).getPropertyValue('font-size');
```

This will give you the actual font size of the element, after any CSS has been applied.

Comment: sorry - didn't mean to edit your question. Rolled back my change.

Comment: @matis: Thank you for the clarification, much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("heading").style.fontSize
```

Will only get styles that are set inline like:

```
<h1 id="heading" style="font-size:16px">My Site</h1>`
```

To get the styles set from a stylesheet use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle):

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("heading"), null).getPropertyValue("font-size");
```

**With inline styling:**

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("heading").style.fontSize)
```

```html
<h1 id="heading" style="font-size:16px">My Site</h1>
```

**With stylesheet styling**

```js
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("heading"), null).getPropertyValue("font-size"))
```

```css
#heading{
   font-size: 16px;
   color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="heading">My Site</h1>
```

Comment: @jo8691: Thank you for the clarification and the MDN link. Much appreciated