# Get computed font size for DOM element in JS ... after scale

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scale

Is there a way to get the computed font size of a DOM element  .. after scale attribute of parent element has been applied?

In the example below there are two text blocks, each with `font-size: 49px` but one appears within a parent element that has `transform: scale(0.741)` in its CSS.

I would expect the first element's font size to be 49px and the second to be (49px * 0.741) = 36.3px.

Is there a way to get the font size after scaling?

```html
<div id="unscaled">
      <span id="entry1" style="font-size: 49px">Australia</span>
</div>
<div id="output1"></div>

<div id="scaled"  style="transform: scale(0.741)">
    <span id="entry2" style="font-size: 49px">Australia</span>
</div>
<div id="output2">
```

I'd like to simply iterate over each span and get its computed style.  But it seems that jQuery is returning the unscaled font size ("49px") rather than the scaled (0.741*49 = 36.3px)

```
$("#output1").text($("#entry1").css('font-size')) // 49px
$("#output2").text($("#entry2").css('font-size')) // 49px not 36.3px
```

Codepen here:  https://codepen.io/__proto__/pen/WNLByMZ?editors=1111

see [Get computed font size for DOM element in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955048/get-computed-font-size-for-dom-element-in-js)

Comment: You can get the `scaleFactor` after the scale transformation has been applied from window object. Have you tried that?

Comment: @mandy8055 I haven't but that may be the answer. Are you on CodeMentor? I can set up a paid session

Comment: @mandy8055 Brilliant!  That works `let el = $("#entry2)[0]; let scaleX = el.getBoundingClientRect().width / el.offsetWidth;`   Post as a solution and I'll mark that as the answer. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Getting the `scaleFactor` after the scale transformation has been applied from the `window` object would get you to your solution and since you have already figured out the final solution by yourself; just posting this as the answer here:

```js
$("#output1").text($("#entry1").css('font-size'))
$("#output2").text($("#entry2").css('font-size'))

let elemt2 = $("#entry2")[0]
var scaleX = elemt2.getBoundingClientRect().width / elemt2.offsetWidth;
$("#output3").text(scaleX)
```

```css
* {
  border: 1px dashed grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="unscaled">
      <span id="entry1" val="Australia" style="font-size: 49px">Australia</span>
    </div>
  <div id="output1"></div>

  <div id="scaled"  style="transform: scale(0.741)">
    <span id="entry2" val="Australia" style="font-size: 49px">Australia</span>
  </div>
  <div id="output2"></div>
    <div id="output3"></div>
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer as your insight solved my use case and saved my night.  However, for anyone else looking at this answer using the id `#scaled` and the specific split by/index may work for this very specific example but may not work for other cases where the transform has other elements, etc.

Comment: @prototype Cool, I have now clearly understand what was your expectations. As a generic approach your solution makes more sense and have updated my answer with your code

Comment: I know SO convention is not to say thanks, but seriously, thanks!